# How do I add an import to the service proto file in a golang project with a buf?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, buf

I have such a project structure:

```
vgm:
 -music:
   -app:
      -cmd
      -go.mod
   -migrations
   -proto:
      -buf.yaml
      -music_service:
         -album:
            -v1:
               -album.proto
               -service.proto
.env
```

Here is the alum file :

```
syntax = "proto3";

package music_service.album.v1;

option go_package = "github.com/mygitname/vgm/music/app/gen/go/music/album/v1;pb_music_album";

message Album {
    string album_id = 1;
    string title = 2;
    uint32 create_at = 3;
}
```

Now I want to write a service for this file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package music_service.album.v1;

option go_package = "github.com/mygitname/vgm/music/app/gen/go/music/album/v1;pb_music_album";

import "music_service/album/v1/album.proto";

service AlbumService {
    rpc CreateAlbum(CreateAlbumRequest) returns (CreateAlbumResponse) {}
}
  

message CreateAlbumRequest {
    string title = 1;
}

message CreateAlbumResponse{
    Album album = 1;
}
```

And the import in this file does not work. If you run the command `buf lint` , then writes the following error:

```
proto\music_service\album\v1\service.proto:7:8:music_service/album/v1/album.proto: does not ex exist
```

I am writing grpc for the second time . Everything was fine the previous time. I don't understand the reason for the error. Does it depend that there is no `go.mod` here? I looked at the examples and it seems that this is not necessarily in the proto file. What could be the mistake ?

Comment: The fact that the error starts with `proto\musi...` is suspicious. Please confirm that `buf.yaml` is in the `proto` folder? (based on the error I'd guess its in the `music` folder).

Comment: @Brits yes, it is in the proto folder, but the launch is made from the music folder

Comment: OK; I have replicated your setup (as far as I can) and `buf lint` does not return any errors. So it looks like the issue is something not provided so far - please add the contents of your `buf.yaml` and confirm what version of `buf` you are using.

Comment: Upgraded to buf 1.12.0 (from 1.11.0) and can now duplicate (works fine if I run `buf lint` from the `proto` folder but not from the parent). I suspect this is a bug...

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like `buf lint` (and `generate`, `breaking`, and other subcommands) to work from the root of your project, you may need a `buf.work.yaml` in the root of your project: https://docs.buf.build/reference/workspaces.

If that doesn't help, we're always available to help in our Slack: https://buf.build/links/slack.